# Commerce - show description of discount without coupon applied to cart

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

We can retrieve description of discount applied to cart that has its own coupon like this:

```
craft.commerce.discounts.getDiscountByCode(cart.couponCode).description
```

Is it possible for discount that do not have coupons and are applied automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there is a much better way, but I use something like this, looping over all cart adjustments, checking the type of adjustment.

We use the `adjustment.sourceSnapshot` for the coupon code, otherwise access the attributes on the adjustment directly, which is a `Discount` model.

```
        {% for adjustment in cart.adjustments if adjustment.type == "discount" %}
            {% set isCoupon = adjustment.sourceSnapshot.code ??? false %}              
            {% if isCoupon %}
                Coupon: {{ adjustment.sourceSnapshot.code }}
            {% else %}
                {{ adjustment.name }}<br />
                {{ adjustment.description }}
            {% endif %}

         {% endfor %}
```

...that works.

Documentation, such as it is, is here:
https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/adjusters.html#adjusting

And the available attributes for a discount model:
https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v3/craft-commerce-models-discount.html#app

(or src: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/blob/master/src/models/Discount.php)

(Honestly, though, even looking at the documentation now, it's really not obvious how to come to this code....)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your method!